# Coordinates of intersectsWithObject() in fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I took a few days to find a way to look intersection point in a path with `fabric.js`. For the moment, the only way is convert to a polygon with many points (path is totally irregular form, draw with bezier curves and rect curves) and find common points.
Read directly the library, I can show a `Intersection.intersectPolygonPolygon`, it use `oCoords` for find a convergence, but I don't have any idea of why.
This function is used by `intersectsWithObject` too. Anybody knows a clean form to do that?